# How do I create log file to save error in a text file using Selenium Webdriver with C#?

Tags: selenium, c#

I need to create a dll log file using Selenium Webdriver with C#. Errors generated while running the C# code need to saved in this text file using that dll. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Voted to close as offtopic, saving text to files is a typical programming issue and not test related. Not even when it is combined with Selenium as they are not related.

Answer (score 0):

@NarendaC: original post uses Selenium C# not Java

@admin: Sorry, I cannot put a comment. Please move/remove if needed.

Comment: You can edit my answer if needed and specific to language. But core idea I shared. Does it really language specific?

Comment: I agree with your core idea and I don't know the answer too, but I think it is not easy for a guy that works on Selenium .NET binding to convert the idea from Java to C# if he does not have any experience on Java :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the question you are asking but the below lines of codes might help you.

```
string nomfichiersource = "UITestActionLog.html";
            string nomTest = TestContext.TestName.ToString();
            string sourcefile = System.IO.Path.Combine(TestContext.TestResultsDirectory, nomfichiersource);
            string destfile = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"G:\Projects\", nomTest + ".html");
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourcefile, destfile, true);
```

This will generate a html file with the logs.

And this works with MSTest.

Answer (score -1):

Solution -

Its as simple aswe integrate JUnit or TestNG in our Selenium Project. Similar way to use it. Steps are as below:

1. I have used log4j for creation of log file. You can add log4j in your project. Need to download log4j.jar first
2. To add in your selenium project by

   - Right click on your project
   - Click Configure build path
   - From library section, Add external jar file
   - Select the log4j.jar or provide path & Save
3. For log4j, we need to add few line of code in log4j.properties file. Ready code you can refer [here](http://www.guru99.com/tutorial-on-log4j-and-logexpert-with-selenium.html)